# Get post or page id early

Tags: hooks, id

Is there a good solution to get the queried object id really early ... and i mean really early?

I got a hook on after_setup_theme where i need to get the post or page id.

$wp_query->queried_object_id is null at that point.

I did it like so till now:

```
function getID() {

    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $theID = url_to_postid($actual_link);
    if($theID == 0) $theID = get_option('page_on_front');

    return $theID;

}
```

Problem is that with WPML installed there are running some rewrite that seems to interfere with this solution cause example.com/foo is converted to example.com/en/foo

Any suggestions?

Comment: `template_redirect` is the safest I would say

Comment: Strange i thougt a had testet it on init and wp_loaded an it was to late ... on this hook it works just fine as far as is can see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For mee it seems that the template_redirect hook worked. Thanks to Pieter Goosen.

Heres a solution that should work on earlier hooks:

```
function gdymc_object_exists( $object_id ) {

    return ( get_the_title( $object_id ) ) ? true : false;

}

function gdymc_objectID() {


    if( is_numeric( $_GET['page_id'] ) ):

        $object_id = $_GET['page_id'];

    elseif( is_numeric( $_GET['p'] ) ):

        $object_id = $_GET['p'];

    elseif( is_numeric( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) ):

        $object_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );

    else:

        $object_id = 0;

    endif;


    return gdymc_object_exists( $object_id) ? $object_id : false;


}
```